# Building a GPS tracking application in Java

Tags: java, swing, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

I need to build a (PC) software application to get readings from a GPS module and show the modules position in a map.

The module will be attached to a robot, an aerial robot. It's preferred to show it's position on a Google map (or similar, if there's any) and update it in real time.

I don't have any prior experience regarding this kind of a matter. Actually, I don't even know whether this is possible. Any helpful information is highly appreciated..

Comment: Be careful! I believe google-maps "term of use" dosen't allow you to build tracking systems. But I'm not sure about this. OpenStreetMap and OpenLayers should not be a licence problem :)

Comment: What do you know about "the module"? Will it have some kind of Java-Driver and API? Or will it just be NMEA-Readings?

Comment: @WaleryStrauch You mean there's some Google API that can be used for the exact purpose? Or is there any alternative? I think this requirement has arisen before. Then there should be some solutions..

Comment: @Fildor yep, just raw NMEA readings.. ??

Comment: Do you know how to interpret NMEA? You can get all the Fix and Track Data out of those readings, but you need to do some parsing. It's not too hard, though. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183 and http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm and many more ...

Comment: @Fildor yeah yeah that part will be OK. But i don't know what kind of data to be extracted (not how). So do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Well, from NMEA you can get Position, Track, Height, ... you might need to use some magic to translate these to map coordinates, though. But I haven't done that part myself before.

Comment: @Anubis I would like to tell you to read "term of use" of google maps before start implementing it to be sure you are using it in legal way ;) Alternative is OpenStreetMap.

Comment: Can someone please tell me why i got a down vote for the post??? I've posted a real question i'm facing and came here for a solution. am i not supposed to ask something i don't know?

Comment: Yes you are. I got downvoted just this week without any comment for an  accepted answer ... If they at least would tell you why they think your question/answer is worth a down. I'm willing to learn ... so @downvoter: please tell him what you think is bad about his question.

Answer (score 2):

`JXMapViewer` may help you accomplish what you are looking for. [Here's](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html) a somewhat dated article on how to use it.

The nice part is that you can change the backend to whatever mapping service provider you want (See [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/joshy/archive/2006/07/getting_started.html)). The default uses [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).

EDIT: Using JXMapViewer will require the [swingx-ws](http://java.net/projects/swingx-ws) project.

Comment: Wow thanks! think that's just what I was looking for. I'll try that and give a feedback..

Comment: Can you give me the download link for `JXMapViewer`. I couldn't find any..

Comment: See the last edit I made. Could be that swingx-ws requires some other dependencies such as SwingX, but those you should be able to find on java.net as well.

Comment: Have you tried the link? there's nothing to download..

Comment: Not under downloads, but you can still connect to the SVN repository to get the sources.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a GPS module
2. You need to interface the module with your PC (Application) to read GPS data. This  depends on the connectivity the device provides.
3. There should be vendor provided applications which comes with GPS module which will get you LA and LO (Geo details). Use them to dump this info to a file in a periodical way.
4. Make you java app to look for any modifications in the file and get data. Now you could use this data to create paths with google map/ or wiki map